# Chain rule in $2$ variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $z = f(x,y)$ has continuous second order partial derivatives and $x = r^2 + s^2$ and $y = 2rs$, find 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}
$$
So, 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}
= \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\right) 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(2r \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}
+ 2s \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)
= 2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} 
+ 2r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right) 
+ 2s\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)
$$

I understand that the product rule has been used to attain the last equality, however, this would imply that $$\frac{\partial }{\partial r} (2s) = 0$$ Why? Can I not write $s$ as a function of $r$ by rearranging the relations I have at the top of the page? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAF, no, the way the functions have been described in the question imply that:

- $z$ is a function of $x$ & $y$,
- $x$ is a function of $r$ & $s$, and
- $y$ is a function of $r$ & $s$.

The question does not say that $s$ is a function of $r$ (or vice versa). So we can view them to be independent variables. So $\frac {\partial}{\partial r}(2s)=0$.

If you wanted to find $\frac {\partial ^2z}{\partial s^2}$, you would also use that $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}(2r)=0$.

Comment: Why can I not write say $s = (+/-)\sqrt{x - r^2}$?

Comment: Anyone? Thanks!